# Spring doc-openapi-ui don't show Basic error controller on swager UI. How to enable Basic error controller on Swagger ui with Spring doc-openapi-ui

Tags: spring-boot, springfox, springdoc-openapi-ui

How to enable Basic error controller on Swagger ui with Springdoc-openapi-ui?

I was using sprigfox earlier, that shows Basic error controller end points. However, when migrating to springdoc-openapi-ui (spring 2.7.7), I can't see BasicErrorController endpoints.

I want to see BasicErrorController endpoints on swagger ui using spring doc (NOTE: it works if i use springfox, but not with springdoc)
I don't have any other code changes than the pom file.

Can someone please suggest that if it is possible to show BasicErrorController endpoints using springdoc-openapi-ui ?